# How to show all holiday types with the code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For my homework, I have to write sql code to show "Among all the orders in 2015, calculate the number of days for each holidaytype, and the average sales per day for each holidaytype. Exclude holidaytype=NULL. Sort the results by the average sales per day from high to low."

This is the code that I have been trying to use

```
select distinct holidaytype, sum(AvgSales) as AvgSales, sum(NumDays) as NumDays
from(
Select min(holidaytype) as holidaytype, count(order_date) as cnt, count(numholidays) as NumDays, avg(o.sales*o.quantity) as AvgSales
from orderline o, orders1 o1, calendar c  
where o.Order_ID=o1.Order_ID  and datepart(yyyy,order_date)= 2015 and holidaytype is not null) J
group by holidaytype
go
```

In the output, only 1 holiday type is showing but I am supposed to have 6 or 7 different holiday types.

Comment: This cannot be answered without knowing more about the data you're working with. Please add enough sample data to be able to test your SQL.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, since your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: For sample data, should I just show what is being returned?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by Holiday Type, so it doesn't make sense to aggregate it, which isn't what you want anyway, according to your question.

So instead of this:

```
Select min(holidaytype) as holidaytype,
```

You should do this:

```
Select holidaytype,
```